# javaPOS printing over shared printer

Tags: java, printing, javapos

I'm trying to setup my project for printing with the citizen ct-s310ii printer.

It works when working on the PC where the usb cable is plugged.

Problems surfaced when I've shared the printer with another pc. All my attempts have failed.

Is there a way to print with javaPOS over a shared printer?

Comment: @Yve well i've tried to connect printer with *right click / connect* over shared printer on the pc i needed then went to port tab to get port name and tried to modify jpos.xml with that name; tried to install over lpt1 redirecting over shared printer with net use and again modify jpos.xml but any attempt i've made when i claim() the printer i have exceptions like: jpos.JposException: The physical device can not be claimed for exclusive access.  I'm pretty sure i'm doing something wrong..not sure what tho.

Comment: Did you ever got it working? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: no. To get something to work i had to change printer to the citizen CT-S601 with lan port and finally i've got the whole thing working.